# DDD: Aggregate Roots without persistence

Tags: aggregate, domain-driven-design, persistence, data-modeling

I have a question regarding the persistence of aggregate roots.

In my case, I have an `Calendar` Aggregate. On each possible day within the calendar (infinite days) I can have one or more `Meetings`.

From my perspective, it would not be feasible to move the `Meeting` entity into the `Calendar` aggregate because that would require me to always fetch all Meetings when a calendar is loaded.

Instead I came up with an `CalendarDay` aggregate that keeps track of the `Meetings` on each day.

Now my question: The `CalendarDay` entity does not really have additional meta-data, It´s just there to handle invariants within one day. So, is it necessary to store such a `CalendarDay` in the database? I could simply make it "virtual" by assigning it a composite id that consists of both the `calendarId` and a specific `date`.

I would however create an repository for it that always returns a `CalendarDay` for a given `calendarId` and `date`. In case when there are no meetings on that day, the meetings would just be an empty list.

Is that something you would do in DDD or is the actual persistence of aggregate roots in some kind of data-storage mandatory?

Comment: wouldn't your user need to view the meetings for one calendar day? if your aggregate is the CalendarDay then if your invariants for that day apply e.g. only one meeting for a specific time  then you should save it on the db and then again fetch one CalendarDay if your user needs to check the calendar for that day

Answer (score 0):

The AR could certainly be transient, but which approach would you use to prevent concurrency conflicts on that given day? If you have a stored AR instance you could implement transparent optimistic locking with a version and the row-level write lock of the DB would do the trick. You'd also have a unique constraint on `date` to cover creation conflicts.

Whether or not you make the AR transient I'd probably still have a `CalendarDay` repository which consumes & returns `CalendarDay` instances. Persisting an entry for the `CalendarDay` wrapper AR itself then becomes an implementation detail.